# Importing to xtext using environment variables

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, xtext

In my language I have include statements which can have relative or absoloute paths of another file. I need to be able to reference objects defined in this other file. I tried using importURI but it doesn't work. All I tried was to add this rule:

```
Include:
    'INCLUDE' '='  importURI=STRING ';'
;
```

Now I have a question about environment variables. Since this grammar is developed previously and there are many test files based on this grammar I need to make my xtext parser to support all we had before. One of these is the ability to import another file using environment variables in the path.

I tried defining the environment variables for the project and then link the files based on these variables, but the problem is importURI string doesn't get teh environment variable.

Assume I have file 1 defined in project which has a link to file to like:

INCLUDE = "${VAR1}/file2.foo";

VAR1 is defined and file2 is linked to project based on VAR1.

This doesn't work unfortunately, do you know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by overwriting the `ImportUriGlobalScopeProvider.getImportUris` method.

The problem was `importURI` is working on the files linked to the workspace or project. So, in my case I linked the files automatically to a dummy project in the `getimportUris` method.